# drupal theme says not compatible

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-themes

I have a theme that has been working the entire time ive been developing the site, now all the sudden randomly, drupal started telling me "This version is not compatible with Drupal 7.x". B

Below is my info file, am I missing something. I havent updated drupal yet so i know nothing changed there the last change I made was update a url in a link. I tried reverting all my changes ive made today back to a version i know for a fact worked fine earlier today, and still nothing.

```
name = My Thene
description = My Theme.
core = 7.x
engine = phptemplate

stylesheets[all][0] = css/reset.css
stylesheets[all][1] = css/layout.css

regions[featured] = Featured
regions[content] = Content
regions[sidebar_first] = Sidebar first
regions[sidebar_second] = Sidebar second
```

Im at a lose for what could be causing this, since its been working for so long untill tonight. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Comment: No sure but try adding styles without the `0` and `1`.

Comment: Maybe it it's a new line issue.

Comment: Remove 0 and 1 from the stylesheets array as also as the 'engine' parameter and flush all caches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was unrelated to drupal its self. The site is being hosted in a windows environment and when the files were updated somehow the option to encrypt files became checked , causing php not to be able to read the files.